# Neo4j browser :style command missing a parameter

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j browser 3.0.1, and I'm trying to access the `:style` menu. Unfortunately, when I do `:style`, as per the instructions [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization) (under advanced styling), I get the following error:

`:style command missing a parameter - grass url, grass style data or reset`

I can't find any documentation on what this means or how to resolve it. Is it possible the style popup editor is gone in this version of Neo4j? How can I do advanced styling?